# AWS Bitnami Wordpress - SELECT command denied to user

Tags: wpdb, phpmyadmin

I'm using Amazon Web Services (AWS) Wordpress which uses Bitnami.

I've created a test template, wrote a SELECT statement to test pulling data from the database, uploaded the template, selected the template for a page, and previewed it.  Here are the results.

> WordPress database error: [SELECT command denied to user 'bn_wordpress'@'localhost' for table 'wp_comments']
>
> SELECT * FROM wp_.wp_comments WHERE comment_ID = 2

This is the statement from the template PHP file.

```
$id = "2";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->prefix.wp_comments WHERE comment_ID = $id";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach( $results as $result ) {

    echo $result->name."<br>";

}
```

The database for the Bitnami Wordpress install is using phpMyAdmin and the database name is **bitnami_wordpress** and the table is named **wp_comments**.

I have selected both the database bitnami_wordpress and the wp_comments table and checked their privileges using the phpMyAdmin GUI.  I opened up "Edit Privileges" to double check and everything is selected.

> Type --> wildcard: bitnami_wordpress
>
> Privileges --> ALL PRIVILEGES
>
> Grant --> Yes

All I'm trying to do is figure out how to pull data from the database and place it on pages so I can develop some templates for my WordPress site.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the user `bn_wordpress` have ALL the Privileges? Run this `SELECT * FROM information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES` and see or use the PHPMyAdmin view to verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that has thrown me off in the past. You actually see the error that talking about the Privileges, but the actual error is that the database doesn't exist!

You are searching for database name `wp_` where there is only `bitnami_wordpress`.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bitnami_wordpress.wp_comments WHERE comment_ID = $id";
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried $wpdb->bitnami_wordpress.wp_comments but obviously that didn't work.  I didn't realize I could just remove $wpdb and call it directly.  Thank you again.